# How to remove required disk space/size information from Inno Setup components?

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to hide the column that shows required disk space. How to achieve this?

[image]

I tried to google for this problem, but found nothing. Not sure if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Upon entering the "components" page, clear `ItemSubItem` property of all items of `WizardForm.ComponentsList`.

```pascal
<event('CurPageChanged')>
procedure CurPageChangedHideComponentSizes(CurPageID: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectComponents then
  begin
    for I := 0 to WizardForm.ComponentsList.Items.Count - 1 do
      WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemSubItem[I] := '';
  end;
end;
```